ETH smart contract
Some time ago I invested money on the ethereum wallet app in the link eqqkl.top. It showed me a few days ago that I could claim the 4 eth reward. After I pressed the "claim" button, it showed me a smart contract from which I understood nothing. After contacting the site's support desk, I learned that I had to pay the $3500 USDT surcharge within 6 days or my money that I had in my wallet would be lost. I don't know completely what to do now. I just want my money back that was taken from me
